# Hibernate: which one is better way: saving source or target in many to one association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-many

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
@OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
public Troop getTroop() {
...
}
```

I do something like this:

```
Troup t = new Troup();
t.getSoldiers().add(soldier);
```

This saves troop and soldier also. Foreign key is also added since soldier is the owner. But which one is better way, I mean saving toop or soldier using:

```
Troop t = .....     // Get troop from session
Soldier s = new Soldier();
s.setTroop(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will arrive at the same result with both approaches. However, I suppose that saving individual `Soldier` entities is a little more efficient:

- the persistence provider does not need to traverse a collection
- the code corresponds better to what happens in the DB - only the `Soldier` table gets updated anyway.

However, perhaps you should think about which business concept fits better, meaning whether are you working with individual `Soldiers` or with `Troops` at this point in the application.

- adding a `Soldier` to a `Troop` or
- assigning a `Troop` to a `Soldier`

The difference may be subtle, but depending on you business case either one may be the more readable and comprehensible solution.

Comment: "the persistence provider does not need to traverse a collection in search of changes"
The collection will already get traversed when we do     t.getSoldiers().add(soldier)

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. Have dropped the last part of the bulletpoint. I am not quite sure about how Hibernate tracks dirty entites under the hood. If you know a good to-the-point reference, I would appreciate a link.

Comment: From experience, the way that hibernate manages dirty entities is not something that you should ever have to be concerned about. Its messy and eats memory like a starving man eats at a bacon buffet, but it works pretty well as long as your collections aren't too massive (<50,000 objects). For inserts it doesn't really matter, but you should carefully consider which direction you call selects/updates from, to avoid the n+1 select problem.

Comment: Efficient solution: SELECT * FROM CHILD WHERE PARENT_ID = ?, Inefficient solution: SELECT * FROM PARENT WHERE PARENT_ID = ?; SELECT * FROM CHILD WHERE CHILD_ID = PARENT.CHILD[n].ID repeated n times where n is the number of children for that parent. If you google Hibernate n+1 select problem, you'll find tons of documentation. If you use SelectType.SUBSELECT, you'll avoid it. It happens when Hibernate tries to populate your collection using a left outer join.

Comment: @JamesMassey Can you please elaborate more on how n+1 problem will arise in this case.
Also, When I save target entity (establishing bi-directional links) I can see Hibernate generating Join SQL to retrieve collection in Troop. 
But If I save target (whithout modifying collection in troop), hibernate generates insert query only and no Join sql is generated (as no collection is being loaded).
`Troop t = (Troop) session.get(Troop.class, 1);
 soldier.setTroop(t);
 Session.save(soldier);`

But question arises, is it the right way: Saving target as shown above or we shall add it to collection also.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a bidirectional association it's **mandatory** to set both sides of this association. You shouldn't just set one side, while leaving the other end in a inconsistent state.

If you are to change it into a unidirectional association then the @ManyToOne side is more efficient to manage:

```
Troop t = .....  
Soldier s = new Soldier();
s.setTroop(t);
```

Using the @OneToMany side will require you to fetch the Set prior to adding a new element. This is mandatory since a Set doesn't allow duplicates therefore requiring to have the collection initialized in order to to enforce the uniqueness policy.

All in all:

1. For bidirectional associations you should set both sides. Setting just one side might lead to very subtle bugs.
2. The @ManyToOne unidirectional association performs better than the @OneToMany unidirectional alternative.